# How to add a marker on Google map v2 using overlay?

Tags: android, google-maps, overlay, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

i am working on a project, where i have to add a marker using overlay to existing Google map.
i have multiple markers along with `infoWindowAdapter`,for these i must pass title and snippet. I need one more marker to show only title(i can't directly add a marker with only title,since i used `infoWindow` for markers it will asks for snippet and ended up with null pointer exception)

I tried this

```
LatLng currenLoc = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+currenLoc, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        GroundOverlayOptions curLoc = new GroundOverlayOptions().image(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.mrk1)).position(currenLoc, 350f, 350f);
        gMap.addGroundOverlay(curLoc);
```

but it shows only a marker like picture not an exact marker. So how to add a marker using ground overlay.?

Comment: add `Marker` like `mMap.addMarker(........)` what is wrong on this?

Comment: i used infoWindowAdapter and infoWindowClickListener where i coded to show both title and snippet. But i don't need snippet and click event in this particular marker.

Comment: First of all clear your Question. What you want actually?

Comment: and i can't use 2 Google map object in a single activity.

Comment: Post your code what you tried till now.

Comment: Ok i have multiple markers, on tapping those markers it shows infoWindow with title and snippet. For that i need both title and snippet. 
I need one more marker just to show my current location in its title field.
i added this infoWindow to my Google map object. like this 

gMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter() {

      @Override
      public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {}

so i can't directly add one more marker to gMap object like gMap.addMarker. because it asks for snippet(i don't want snippet here)

I think i cannot use one more Google map object in same activity

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51154/discussion-between-simple-plan-and-h-app-y)